# gradle custom task with package name

Tags: gradle

I see that when I create a custom task type in gradle, with different package name than 'org.gradle', I cannot directly declare the task in my build file with just type name. I need to give fully qualified name of the task

If the package is 'foo.bar' then

```
task blockC(type: TestNGBlock) {
    testngxml = "tests/testng-lrga-blockC.xml"
}
```

doesnt' work. I need to write as below:

```
task blockC(type: foo.bar.TestNGBlock) {
    testngxml = "tests/testng-lrga-blockC.xml"
}
```

Is there a way like import in java, where I can specify gradle the package names to look into for resolving type, so that I can use the former approach to define task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Import in `build.gradle` works exactly the same as in pure java class.

```
import foo.bar.TestNGBlock

task blockC(type: TestNGBlock) {
  testngxml = "tests/testng-lrga-blockC.xml"
}
```

Comment: if you're shipping these tasks with a plugin you can use a workaround to do project.ext.TestNGBlock = foo.bar.TestNGBlock. This way you don't need an import statement if you applied that plugin in your project